# window.opener cross domain call using javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm having a subdomain url like 123.example.com, in that I'm doing Oauth login using Google or Facebook.Now procedure is like when I click on the login with google or facebook , a window pops up and will get the details, after getting the details I want to show the details in the parent window. so I'm using window.opener.$("#first_name").val(firstName);, I'm getting a error like this Error: Permission denied to access property '$'.
If it is not subdomain its working fine. How to get the values to main window.

Answer (score 6):

Two options for you:

#### `document.domain`

If both windows are in the same root domain and the issue is the subdomain, you *may* be able to solve it using the [`document.domain` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.domain), e.g. in the window that's on a `123.example.com`, you can do this:

```
document.domain = "example.com";
```

...to allow it to talk with windows on `example.com.`

#### Web Messaging

The more general (and modern) solution is [web messaging](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/), which allows cooperative cross-origin communication in places where the SOP would normally prevent direct communication. So we have `http://parent-origin/parent.html` and it wants to open and communicate with `http://child-origin/child.html`. In `http://parent-origin/parent.html`:

```
// Listen for messages
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    // If we get a message from the child, and the message is asking for
    // us to send the info...
    if (e.origin === "http://child-origin" && e.data === "send-info") {
        // ...send it
        log("Got request from child, sending info");
        e.source.postMessage({command: "info", info: { /*...data goes here...*/ }}, e.origin);
    }
}, false);
```

In `http://child-origin/child.html`:

```
// Listen for messages
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    var info;

    // If the message is from the parent and it says it has the info...
    if (e.origin === "http://parent-origin" && e.data && e.data.command === "info") {
        // Use info
        info = e.data.info;
        log("Info is " + JSON.stringify(info));
    }
}, false);

// Ask the opener to send us the info
opener.postMessage("send-info", "http://parent-origin");
```

You may be able to eliminate the part where the child asks the parent for the info depending on how you're opening the child (e.g., if the parent window has a means of knowing that the child is fully loaded and ready for messages). Having the child *ask* is a pretty good way to make sure it's ready to receive the info, though.

Originally, web messaging only allowed passing strings, but modern browsers allow passing objects which get cloned. Also note that if you have `canvas` objects or similar, you can pass them in the third parameter of `postMessage` so they get *transferred*: The sender no longer has access to them, just the receiver. This lets us avoid copying large things (where possible) while also avoiding issues of multiple threads having simultaneous access to the same data.

Comment: Thanks,but this won't support for early browsers,As I'm using google appengine so I will go with Channel Api.

Comment: I got the solution,Google and Facebook redirect url has a state parameter, in that we can send our data and receive it, event its cross domain.