# Why is my callback function undefined?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a page defined as follows:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p>
            <input id="myButton" type=button onclick=window.open('LandingPage.html'); value="Launch Search App">
        </p>
    </div>
    <script>
        function cb(msg) { console.log(msg); }
        myButton.addEventListener('click', cb);
    </script>
</body>
```

This page is responsible for setting up a callback function for a secondary page. The callback function seems to be setup, at least according to F12 Developer Tools where I see a `PointerEventPrototype` created. The `PointerEventPrototype` is not present if I comment out the line containing the `addEventListener()` that sets up the callback so I believe I have it working so far.

Clicking the button on the first page launches another window containing the second page, shown below:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p>
            <input type=button value="Save" onclick="click_function()">
        </p>
    </div>
    <script>
        function click_function() {
            var message = "Save button clicked!";

            console.log(message);
            cb(message);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The second page contains a Save button that is intended to respond to the callback function setup on the first page. When the Save button is clicked, "Save button clicked!" is output to the console but the following line, `cb(message)`, throws an error that says `cb` is undefined. How can this be undefined? Do I need to call the callback function using a different syntax?

Comment: Your `cb()` function is defined in one page, and you're trying to call it from a *different* page.

Comment: Your two functions should be defined in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cb` exists only in the first page. If they're on the same origin, your second page can refer to the global `window` of the first page via its `opener` global, so:

```
opener.cb(message);
```

That only works because `cb` is a global on the first page, so it's a property of the `window` object.

Having said that, though, it may be a cleaner design to use [web messaging](https://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/), and it comes with the benefit that it will work cross-origin as well. Rather than having one page reach out and call a function in another, with web messaging you post a message to the page and let it handle the message however it sees fit. There's a complete, simple example in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24408394/157247).

Comment: My understanding of how callbacks actually work may be wrong and web messaging may be what I need. When setting up the callback, I thought I was sending code to be run at a point in the future. In this example, the Save button simulates the save process and returns a message to the main page. Using the opener.cb() approach, I was simply running code that exists in one page inside another. The message was output to the console of the second page, not actually sent back to the first page to appear on that console. This is where is seems to me web messaging might be the better fit.